# Regex to match Image Url

Tags: regex, url, pattern-matching

I am trying to get a simple regex to verify that a URL contains the ending figures

```
var testRegex = /^https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$/;
var imageUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery";
if (testRegex.test(imageUrl)) {
  alert('Not Match');
}
```

And this *should* trigger `alert('Not Match');` and it doesn't ? See http://jsfiddle.net/UgfKn/

What's going on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean:

```
if (!testRegex.test(imageUrl)) {
  alert('Not Match');
}
```

Comment: yeah haha stupid error by me :) - does the regex look OK at least for image url's ?

Comment: append lower-case i after the regular expression: `/^https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$/i`, in case of upper-case characters.

Comment: In case someone else finds this answer in a while, the regex provided doesn't support numbers in urls (I also added BMP support), so the modified version is : `/^https?:\/\/(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)$/i`

Answer (score 1):

`testRegex.test` will evaluate to True if `testRegex` DOES match.
ie

```
if (testRegex.test(imageUrl)) {
  alert('Match');
} else {
  alert('Not match');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `!` in the if condition

```
if ( ! testRegex.test(imageUrl1) ) {
    alert('Not Match');
}
```

See 
http://jsfiddle.net/UgfKn/1/